# Functionality of Documents status in Galaxy flow

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

What is the Functionality and working of Documents status (Documents Ready,Documents validate, Documents error, Documents processed and Documents error handled) in Galaxy flow in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document status is a property of a document in the `Document library` of [Galaxy](http://www.google.dk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=axapta%20galaxy&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CG4QFjAB&url=http://www.columbusit.ae/Admin/Public/DWSDownload.aspx?File=Files%252FFiler%252FBusiness%2bNeed%252FColumbus_Galaxy_UK.pdf&ei=uv0rT4HUKune4QTp8MyWDg&usg=AFQjCNH1UjOe4DapZ0HEBAPen5WS-zomjw).

Status:

- Ready - the document ready for consumption in the next flow line
- Processed - the document has been consumed with succes
- Error - the document has been consumed but the process failed
- Error handled - the document has been consumed but the process failed, it was manually handled

A document is usually created in the first flow line, being read from a file or an ODBC connection. The document will then have status `Ready`.

The second flow line will then consume the document, most like by using the media `Axapta DB` to insert or update the records of an AX table. The document will then have status `Processed` (if succesful).

Comment: Could u tell me about "Documents validate" status?

Comment: It seems its use is disabled. The tab `TAB_Validate` in form `GxyLocFlow` is not visible. I used the cross reference, you could use that as well.